# Shuffling two lists separately in Python

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

here is my code:

```
import random
from random import shuffle

a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = ['a','b','c','d']
c = ['w','x','y','z']
d = ['w','x','y','z']
indices = random.sample(range(len(a)), len(a))
a = map(a.__getitem__, indices)
b = map(b.__getitem__, indices)
shuffle(c)
shuffle(d)
print a,b,c,d
```

What this code does is it shuffles a and b in the same order, and shuffles c and d in their own order. What I am trying to do now is making two longer lists composed of a and c, and b and d, and put them in a randomized order. What I want though is for a and b stay the same order across lists. Is there any way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Edit:

I would like the output to look something like this, where lists a&b correspond and c&d are just randomized independently.

['d','x','w','b','a','y','c','z']

['d','z','y','b','a','x','c','w']

Comment: Please show an example of the output you're looking for.

Comment: Will do, I'll add it above.

Comment: Do you want a and b not just to stay in the same *order* but in the same *positions* in the new combined list?  For instance, could your new lists be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']` and `['z', 'a', 'y', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'w', 'd']`, where abcd are in the same relative order in both lists, but in different places?

Comment: Also, is it always the case that the elements of a/b are distinct from the elementrs of c/d, or is it possible that some elements could be contained in both?

Comment: *"a and b stay the same order "* -- same order or also same *position* in the result? Must this be fast?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` the same initially? If yes: create `a` first, shuffle, and duplicate afterwards.

Comment: If the elements from `a` and `b` always stay in the same position, you can sample indexes, e.g, `random.sample(range(len(a)+len(c),4)` and and put the four elements from `a` into the combined list at those slots, and then fill in the ones from `c` and `d` in left to right order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we shuffle `c` and `d` first, randomly sampling from the concatenated lists `ac` and `bd` gives the required result (I'm using Python 3 so the printing requires parentheses):

```
import random
from random import shuffle

a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = ['a','b','c','d']
c = ['w','x','y','z']
d = ['w','x','y','z']
shuffle(c)
shuffle(d)
# print a,b,c,d
print (a,b,c,d)
ac = a + c
bd = b + d
indices = random.sample(range(len(ac)),len(ac))
ac = list(map(ac.__getitem__, indices))
bd = list(map(bd.__getitem__, indices))
#print ac, bd
print (ac, bd)
```

Output as follows:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'w', 'z', 'y']['y', 'z', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z', 'c', 'x', 'b', 'w', 'd', 'a'] ['x', 'w', 'c', 'y', 'b', 'z', 'd', 'a']
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @Jan-Philip Gehrcke who points out that using `numpy` indexing (as follows) is much faster when the lists are large:

```
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np

a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = a[:]
c = ['w','x','y','z']
d = c[:]
shuffle(c)
shuffle(d)
# print a,b,c,d
print (a,b,c,d)
ac = np.array(a + c)
bd = np.array(b + d)
indices = list(range(len(ac)))
shuffle(indices)
ac = ac[indices]
bd = bd[indices]
#print ac, bd
print (ac, bd)
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension for creating the new lists based on the random index sample is nicer and even *slightly* faster on my system (read: it is not slower, so use the nicer syntax :-)).

Comment: Corresponding benchmark code: `timeit.timeit("l2=[l[i] for i in idcs]", setup="from random import sample as s; N=10**6; idcs=s(range(N), N); l=list(range(N))", number=10)` -- `l2=[l[i] for i in idcs]` takes 2.14 seconds on my system, `l2=list(map(l.__getitem__,idcs))` takes 2.16 seconds.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: I agree and I would have used the list comprehension if it was my code. I used the map in this case because the OP had used that approach in the question.

Comment: Also note that a pure numpy-based indexing approach is significantly faster. The same benchmark as above, with `newarray = oldarray[randomindex]`-based indexing is about 20 times faster: `>>> timeit.timeit("l2=l[idcs]", setup="import numpy as np; N=10**6; idcs=np.random.randint(0,N,N); l=np.array(list(range(N)))", number=10)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
# make b later
c = ['w','x','y','z']
d = ['w','x','y','z']
random.shuffle(a)
random.shuffle(c)
random.shuffle(d)
b = list(a)

x = a + c
random.shuffle(x)

y = []
for item in x:
    if item in a:
        y.append(b.pop())
    else:
        y.append(d.pop())

>>> x
['w', 'z', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'y']
>>> y
['z', 'y', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'w']
```

If you want a and b to be in the same random order, it's more convenient to just shuffle a, and then make b a copy of it.  Then to make the new lists x and y, I first make x by shuffling `a + c`, and then build up y by going through `x` and adding a member from `b` or `d` depending on whether the corresponding element of `x` is in `a` or `c`.

This approach assumes that the set of elements in a and b is disjoint from those in c and d.  The current version also destroys b and d in the process of making `y`, although this could be fixed with a slightly more cumbersome algorithm (keeping track of an index into `b` and `d` and grabbing elements by index instead of popping).

Comment: Your `if item in a` approach assumes that these lists are non-overlapping sets. Also, you basically shuffle `c` twice. Also, I like `b = a[:]` more than `b=list(a)` :-).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Yes, I added a note at the bottom to mention that assumption.  I like `list(a)` more than `a[:]` :-).

Answer (score 0):

how about random shuffling c first and then zipping to a ?

```
    import random
    a=['a','b','c','d']
    b=['a','b','c','d']
    c=['w','x','y','z']
    d=['w','x','y','z']
    random.shuffle(c)
    a_c = zip(a,c)
    print a_c
```

[('a', 'y'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'w')]

The order of list a is not changed while list c is shuffled randomly.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I think he wants `a` and `c` to be randomly interleaved, not strictly alternating one element from `a` with one from `c`.